# returning a subset of mySQL FULLTEXT search results

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am trying to combine FULLTEXT search with simple WHERE, and I'm getting too many results.

I'm testing by running the SQL in phpmyadmin, before I turn it into a stored procedure.

When I run:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE MATCH(title,designer_manufacturer,countryoforigin_materials,additional_info)
AGAINST ('+glass +vase' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

(to get all glass vases in catalog) it works just fine, giving me the 14 results I expect.

There's another field in mytable, "groupID", having values A/B/C. I want to filter these results by group -- or conversely, only run the match on one group.

When I run

```
SELECT *, 
MATCH (title,designer_manufacturer,countryoforigin_materials,additional_info) 
AGAINST ('+glass +vase' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
FROM mytable WHERE groupID = 'B'
```

it returns *everything* in Group B! So then I tried

```
SELECT *, 
MATCH (title,designer_manufacturer,countryoforigin_materials,additional_info) 
AGAINST ('+glass +vase' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AS SCORE
FROM mytable WHERE groupID = 'B'
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
```

and it still returns everything, it just puts the results I want first.

How do I limit the results to the ones I want? This is important because I really need to put them in a different order than "BY SCORE".

Thank you.

Red Owl

**ETA: ANSWERED**

At @Vatev 's suggestion, I used:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE MATCH (title, designer_manufacturer,   countryoforigin_materials, additional_info)
AGAINST ('+glass +vase' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND groupID =  'B'
```

and got just (and only) what I want! Thank you very much.

Comment: How about `... WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST(...) AND groupID = 'B'` ?

Comment: YES! @Vatev, you are completely right!